# Java / .NET spawn browser with cookie set

Tags: java, .net, desktop-application

I can spawn a browser from my Java thick client using [java.awt.Desktop](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html).

Apprarently, I can also spawn a browser from my .NET client using [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

My question is, is there a way in both Java / .NET to set a cookie when spawning the browser process? It doesn't look like there is - possibly due to security concerns?

Answer (score 1):

There is not. You could probably add some sort of plugin in the target browser, but that would be with a different mechanism.

What `java.awt.Desktop` does , it just launch the browser. There is no more interaction with it.

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was to spawn an intermediate page like:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(
    new URI("http://localhost/intermediate.html?mytoken=bar")
);
```

Then have a bit of JavaScript to take the request param, set it as a cookie, and then forward onto the destination page.

```
var query = location.search;
var tokenRe = /mytoken=([^?]*)/;
var token = query.match(tokenRe)[1];
document.cookie = 'MYTOKEN=' + token
location.replace('http://localhost/destination')
```

Simples!